# Remove a link tag in head tag

Tags: header, link, tags, head

I never used **Magento** and a client of mine asked me to **remove** an unwanted google **adsense** in his website.

While inspecting, I got this:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com.br/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.mywebsite.com.br" as="script">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com.br/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.mywebsite.com.br"></script>
<link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.mywebsite.com.br" as="script">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.mywebsite.com.br"></script>
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/static/3p_cookie.html">
```

I need to get rid of these things but I can't find where. Through searching I tried to find it in `head.phtml` and `page.xml` or `local.xml` but nothing there.

If you guys could help me, It'd be awesome.

Comment: Normally, you can stop Google adwords on admin panal. Go to Store->Configuration->Sales->Google API->Google AdWords and choose **No** on Enable. But regarding to your link, seems they're generated from another module...

Comment: Yes, it seems that it's from another module because there is no ad api in the path you told me to check

Comment: Just disable it, or removing related codes in template then.

Comment: As I said, i'm new to Magento. Remove in which file ? There's no option to "Disable" it.